# Invert numbers in document using macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I want to write a macro to find numbers and invert them in a document.
for example convert : `123456` to `654321`
I write this macro but it doesnt work :

```
Function inverter(Numbers)
Dim Num As Long
Dim inverted As Long
Num = Numbers
Do Until Num >= 1
    remainder = Num Mod 10
    Num = Num / 10
    inverted = inverted * 10 + remainder
Loop
inverter = inverted
End Function
Sub invert()
Dim a As Long
    Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
           .Text = "([!0-9])([0-9]@)([!0-9])"
           .Replacement.Text = "\1" & a="\2" inverter(a) & "\3"
           .Forward = True
           .Wrap = wdFindContinue
           .Format = False
           .MatchCase = False
           .MatchWholeWord = False
           .MatchKashida = False
           .MatchDiacritics = False
           .MatchAlefHamza = False
           .MatchControl = False
           .MatchWildcards = True
           .MatchSoundsLike = False
           .MatchAllWordForms = False
           .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

When i compile it return this error :

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Compile error:

Expected: end of statement
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Debug the programme - use `F8` key to find out what line causes error!

Comment: `.Replacement.Text = "\1" & a="\2" inverter(a) & "\3"` Check this line. There seems to be a missing `&` and I don't think `a="\2"` will work either.
Also please don't put all the statements in one line, it's impossible to read.

Comment: Addition to my last comment: `a` and `inverter` should probably be changed to deal with strings. `a="\2" & inverter(a)` won't work because `a="\2"` isn't evaluated when the text is replaced but when the replacement text is set so it will return false. `"\2" & inverter("\2")` won't work either because `inverter("\2")` is evaluated at time of definition of replacement.text. I would recommend looking into regular expressions and looping over the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't make sense for me

```
.Replacement.Text = "\1" & a="\2" inverter(a) & "\3"
```

It seems like a combination of assignment, logical evaluation and "error"

I am unable to find a batch replace solution like you need ; so here my suggestion:

I changed your `Invertor` to work with strings instead, because your `Invertor` will return `1` for `1000` instead of `0001` (perhaps this is not considered in Word RegEx)

```
Function Inverter2(nb As String) As String
    Dim bn As String
    For i = 1 To Len(nb)
        bn = Mid(nb, i, 1) & bn
    Next i
    Inverter2 = bn
End Function
```

And here is your `invert` changed

```
Sub invert()
Dim a As Long
    Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
           .Text = "([!0-9])([0-9]@)([!0-9])"
           '.Replacement.Text = "\1" & a="\2" inverter(a) & "\3"
           .Forward = True
           '.Wrap = wdFindContinue
           .Format = False
           .MatchCase = False
           .MatchWholeWord = False
           .MatchKashida = False
           .MatchDiacritics = False
           .MatchAlefHamza = False
           .MatchControl = False
           .MatchWildcards = True
           .MatchSoundsLike = False
           .MatchAllWordForms = False
           '.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
           While .Execute
               Selection.Text = Inverter2(Selection.Text)
           Wend
    End With
    Selection.GoTo What = wdGoToLine, Which = wdGoToFirst
End Sub
```

I removed `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` because the text will be inverted two times so kept same

I also removed your replacement and proceeded one by one.

Comment: thanks for your time , i dont access to my pc now, i will test it tomorrow :)

Comment: test this file [test.docx](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=93208893086428438387) macro **remove** line 2

Comment: @fabrice-lylian-tayou can you test this macro with this file?

Comment: @amini-gazar I am unable to download that doc, my antivirus blocked the website, can you share via dropbox or gg drive ?

Comment: @fabrice-lylian-tayou Share in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bifaypj7vhgtex/test.docx?dl=0)

Comment: I tested the code into that document, at my side it is not removing line but skipping some numbers